What’s the best way to train a model to change a provided image with the provided instructions?
I have a platform where clients of mine can request changes to designs, using drawings and comments. I want to make an AI feature where clients can illustrate their modification request by providing a text input and then select the image that best represents their prompt.
I tried DALL-E. Definitely doesn't work. Other similar services don't seem to be the way to go about it. I think maybe I should train my own AI model, but how?

Could you clarify what experience you already have with ML and image models? It would help when deciding how technical to phrase an answer.
